# How to do same commands but in different iteration styles with if-condition? (Python, code optimization)

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, optimization, prettytable

So, I've got this code:

```
    t = PrettyTable(['first', 'second'])
    if condition:
        for i in data_set[::-1]:
            t.add_row([i['first'], i['second'])
            # ... (multiple other commands)
    else:
        for i in data_set:
            t.add_row([i['first'], i['second'])
            # ... (same multiple commands as above)
```

and I want to shorten the code, so that I only have to write the commands once. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the condition to get the correct iterable then do your stuff

```
items = data_set if condition else data_set[::-1]

for i in items:
    t.add_row([i['first'], i['second'])
```

Comment: @jkeeraa you're welcome, you can accept the answer so ;)